# 'define' is not defined error on RequireJS & Webapp Yo generator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have struggled a few days to figure this out,, but finally I need your help today.
my repo: https://github.com/seoyoochan/bitsnut-web

---

**what I want to achieve**:
 - Load and optimize r.js
 - Write bower tasks for RequireJS and r.js :
   tasks are:  minify & uglify & concatenation for RequireJS, and optimise with r.js on production
 - How to exclude js script tags in `index.html` when using `wiredep` tasks and load them through RequireJS loader?

---

I use Yeoman 'Webapp' generator and generated the scaffold app.

I installed backbone, marionette, text, underscore, and etc via `bower install`
I modified `bower.json` by removing `dependencies` and left only `"requirejs": "~2.1.16"` on `dependencies`. (`devDependencies` is empty)

because I use `[2][grunt-wiredep]`, everything is automatically loaded `bower_components` into `index.html`. 
I modified `.bowerrc` to store dependencies at `app/scripts/vendor`.

However, the problem is that I don't know how to successfully load them through ReuqireJS and not to load the vendors as script tags inside `index.html`.
I have to write some tasks for RequireJS and r.js, but don't know how to achieve this goal ( I installed `grunt-contrib-requirejs` though )

I want to follow the 4th method to make use of `r.js` at https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module. but the issue I encountered was that RequireJS's documentation does suggest to not use `named module`, but `anonymous module`.
I would like to hear various opinions about how I should approach.

I really appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: @PeteTNT I know I don't want it to be included in the index.html, but they were included automatically by 'wiredep'. How could I solve it? And also, are both main.js and config.js correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You load your scripts manually [here](https://github.com/seoyoochan/bitsnut-web/blob/master/app/index.html#L40) and [here](https://github.com/seoyoochan/bitsnut-web/blob/master/app/index.html#L66), rendering the whole point of `requireJS` useless. You also load `main` first [here config.js#L49](https://github.com/seoyoochan/bitsnut-web/blob/master/app/scripts/config.js#L49).

Instead, you should only have this line in your index.html

```
<script data-main="scripts/config" src="scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

And load all your dependencies in that file (like you do with `main`) using `define()` and `require()`. As you have set `exports`, which sets the values as globals, the functions can be empty. Here's an sample:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore", 
    "backbone",
    "marionette",         
    "modernizr"
], function () {
        require([
        "backbone.babysitter", 
        "backbone.wreqr", 
        "text", 
        "semantic"
    ], function () {
        /* plugins ready */
    });

    define(["main"], function (App) {
           App.start();
    });
});
```

Also the `baseUrl` is the same as the directory as your `data-main` attributes folder (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles):

> RequireJS loads all code relative to a baseUrl. The baseUrl is
>   normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main
>   attribute for the top level script to load for a page. The data-main
>   attribute is a special attribute that require.js will check to start
>   script loading.

So I think your `baseUrl` in `config.js` points to `scripts/scripts/`-folder which doesn't exist. It could/should be `vendor/` instead (and remove the vendor part from all of the declarations) or just left empty.

Instead of `wiredep`, you could try using https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs which does similar things to `wiredep` but specially for `bower/requirejs` apps (see: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/7)

Your repo doens't include the dist-folder for `jQuery`, but otherwise here's a working sample of `config.js`: http://jsfiddle.net/petetnt/z6Levh6r/

As for the module-definition, it should be

`require(["dependency1", "dependency2"])`

and the module should return itself. Currently your `main` file sets itself as a dependency

```
require(["main", "backbone", "marionette"], function(App, Backbone, Marionette){
```

As you already set the `backbone` and `marionette` as globals with `exports`, you can again set the function attributes empty, so your main file should look like this:

```
require(["backbone", "marionette"], function(){
  "use strict";
  var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

  App.addInitializer(function(){
    console.log("hello world!");
    Backbone.history.start();
  });

  return App;
});
```

And as you already use `define` to load `main`, don't `require` it again. Instead just call `App.start()` inside the `define` function.

https://jsfiddle.net/66brptd2/ (config.js)

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer! but I have still a few problems when loading files with requireJS. if you `grunt serve` my app from the repo, the console complains a lot of stuff .. and how can I let `config.js` refer to `main.js` ? or let `main.js` refer to `config.js`?

I thought I could just say `require` the defined module file set by `define() method`, am I wrong?

Comment: @seoyoochan, I pulled your updated repo and modified the `config.js` file a bit: see the end of the page for a fiddle. The repo didn't contain the /dist/-folder for `jquery` though. I didn't notice that you (correctly) set the exports, so you can / should leave the define and ready-functions attributes empty.

Comment: Thanks! It almost works now, but when I require ["main"] inside `config.js`. it returns `undefined`.  look at this http://s18.postimg.org/6dcw0l57t/Screen_Shot_2015_03_29_at_1_25_46_AM.png and I updated the repo

Comment: See my edit again, it fixes some issues with the Main.

Comment: Aaand some racing conditions. I think it still could be improved a bit but it finally works :)

Comment: I don't know why my server keeps saying `'define' is not defined.` because define was not defined successfully, `var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();` does not work either and spits out error on console. :/ (updated repo)

Comment: Check your Network-tab. It might be that your servers `baseUrl` is different than the one locally!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74031/discussion-between-seoyoochan-and-pete-tnt).

Comment: I will enter that chat.